# Returning date + taking into consideration time zone difference

Tags: sql

I need to return the races `Start_time` (- 4 hours) to match my time zone, from the below Table:

[image]

```
select Start_time, Race_Name 
from Race_Table
```

But I need something like:  `select (hour, -4)Start_time, Race_Name from Race_Table`

Comment: Removed conflicting DBMS tags - please re-tag your question with the correct DBMS. *(Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They are not the same thing, and the answers would be different for each.)*

Comment: Thank you @Siyual I'm using _SQL Server_ 
Will take this into consideration next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT Race_Name,
       DATE_SUB(Start_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)
FROM Race_Table
```

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT Race_Name,
       DATEADD(HOUR, -4, Start_time)
FROM Race_Table
```